# Assign value to an element of 2-D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create a 2-D array and initialize an element. Here is my code. Similar code used to work in C++ language, but not in Java.

```
class Test{
    int[][] matrix = new int[3][3];
    matrix [1][1] = 2;
}
```

Comment: Place your code in a `main` method.

Comment: Generally when you're getting errors you should include them in your question that way others can help you faster/not have to copy your code and get it running on their machines just to see an error message.

Comment: Of course, I wrote a main method. This is class is just a part of my whole program.

Comment: ... or any method for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code needs to be inside a method, or a static block:

```
matrix [1][1]=2;
```

This works just fine:

```
public static void main (String args[]) {

    int[][] matrix=new int[3][3];
    matrix [1][1]=2;

    System.out.println( matrix [1][1]);
}
```

Comment: The variable isn't static, so it can't be in a static block. However, it can be in a non-static block.

Answer (score 2):

You're **not** allowed to initialize a variable outside a class method or a constructor. The following code should compile just fine.

```
class Test
{
    int[][] matrix = new int[3][3];
    public Test()
    {
            matrix [1][1] = 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be as simple as the code below. Put it in the main method to allow you to run your programs. The code can't be just anywhere. I have coded an alternative shorthand technique for you to understand 2D arrays.

```
public class TwoDArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         int[][] matrix = new int[3][3];
         matrix [1][1] = 2;

         //prints 2
         System.out.println(matrix[1][1]);


         //Alternative technique - shorthand

         int[][] numb = {

                    {1,2,3},
                    {10,20,30},
                    {100,200,300}

            };

        //prints 300
        System.out.println(numb[2][2]);


        //prints all gracefully
            for (int row=0; row<numb.length; row++) {
                for (int col=0; col<numb[row].length; col++) {
                    System.out.print(numb[row][col] + "\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
    }

}
```